# Jenkins illegalArgumentException

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am setting up a Jenkins CI with github. However, after using the github plugin and conneting to a repo, this happend.

[image]
Can anyone please tell me to do ? i have no clue.....

Answer (score 0):

Click the Apply button — and then run Test Connectivity ... with API

If that does not work the only other thing I can think of that might cause this exception is having white spaces in the job name. If you do, try replacing the white spaces with a dash or underscore instead.